# How to display web service exceptions to user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

When I get an exception in my MVC 3 controller from Web service how can I show this message to the user and return to the page he was?

I want to show something to the user like...

If i'm creating an user and the name of the user already exists, so i throw an exception with the message ("the user with the name ... already exists') and i want to get this exception in my controller catch and show to the user as alert or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean show the message to the user and return to the page? Do you want to know an alert box? Or a new page with the error? and then redirect?

Comment: Note that you do _not_ want to show the actual exception to the user, as it may reveal internals of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the error you would like to show to the `ModelState`.

For ex.,

```
public ActionResult CreateUser(User user)
{
    try
    {
       _webServiceProxy.CreateUser(user);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
       ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name already exists");
    }

    return View();
}
```

In the View probably you should have the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` which displays the error to the user.

If you want to display the error message near to the user name field you have to pass the field name as the first parameter.

i.e.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "...");
```

and in the View you have to use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)`

If you want to show the error in an alert box for whatever reason (i don't prefer this) you could achieve that by rendering small script at the bottom of the view. From the controller you have to pass the error to the view through ViewBag.

Controller,

```
ViewBag.Error = "The user name already exists";
```

View,

```
@{
   var error = ViewBag.Error;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   var error = "@error";
   if(error)
     alert(error);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you brow, that's it i wanted, but just one more question, is there a way to show this message in a alert box?

Comment: @user1863014 why would you want to do validation using an alert box? Those things should've been banned 20 years ago, as they are obtrusive. Take a look at [unobtrusive validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html), which is pretty much built in to MVC.